# iPhone as LTE "modem" drops its connection to USB-tethered mini-router

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, tethering

I'm using an old iPhone SE (2016) as a "modem" to access LTE cellular Internet connectivity. I've set up a small, palm-sized router as a USB tethering client of the iPhone (in other words, the iPhone is serving as the router's WAN gateway). The first time I connected the router to the iPhone via Lightning cable, the iPhone asked for confirmation to "trust this computer", which I granted; on subsequent plug-ins, the iPhone recognizes the router and doesn't ask again. (In my use case, this is a remote site where I have a couple of IP cameras installed; the router–iPhone combo provides Internet connectivity to the cams, and this is how I'm able to remotely monitor the cams in real time and download recorded footage.)

The problem I'm having is that the iPhone periodically drops its tethering connection to the router for no apparent reason, and the only way it can be reestablished is for me to personally visit the site, pick up the iPhone, and toggle the "Allow Others to Join" control off and then on again — whereupon the router's tethering connection is immediately restored. (Again, I want to emphasize that no further interaction with the iPhone is required; the router is recognized, and no trust-confirmation dialog is presented).

Of course, visiting the site repeatedly just to manually restore the tethering connection isn't sustainable, so I need a proper solution.

My question in three parts:

- Why is the iPhone dropping the USB tethering service to the router, even though the physical cabling connection between them is undisturbed?
- Why is the iPhone failing to automatically reestablish the tethering service to the router after the interruption?
- How can I make the router–iPhone "gateway" work reliably? What can I do to either prevent the mysterious disconnections, or enable automatic reconnections, of the tethering service?

Thanks.

[Note: the iPhone SE is fully updated to the latest iOS version, currently v14.5.1.]

Comment: Note: I've also posted this question over at Apple Support Communities ([link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252766362)).

Comment: I‘d suspect that the connection is dropped due to inactivity. If that’s the case, can you somehow make sure there is always a little activity, like pinging an ip address every second?

Comment: @not2savvy: Huh, I hadn't thought of that possibility. I'll give your suggestion a try and report back. Thanks!

Comment: @not2savvy: Welp, the cam went offline again a little while ago, within at most two hours of the last clip it captured, which involves Internet access… so I'm pretty sure inactivity time-out isn't the source of the problem. Thanks, though.

Comment: Can you set up the router to use the iPhone’s hotspot? Maybe that works more reliably?

Comment: @not2savvy: I gather that by "use the hotspot" you mean tether wirelessly via Wi-Fi, rather than by USB cable. The router is not an Apple device that can be "logged into the same Apple ID", which I understand is a requirement for automatic engagement of the Wi-Fi hotspot from an iPhone. Connecting the router via cable was my attempt to work around that limitation. Moreover, the cams themselves connect by Wi-Fi, and I previously had them connect directly to the iPhone hotspot, but the connection would always be dropped sooner or later. Hence the router as a go-between.